# How do I add binary numbers and ignore the carry?

Tags: java, binary

Supposing the inputs are two integer values. I want to convert the two integer values to binary, perform binary addition, and give the result with the carry ignored (the integer equivalent). How would I go about doing this.

An idea that comes to mind is to convert them to binary strings in some way and use an algorithm for binary addition, and then ignore the carry (delete the carry character from the string, if the carry exists).

Sample Input

One number : 1
Second number : 3

Sample Output

2
Explanation:
The lowest bit in the sum is 1 + 1 = 0
The next bit is 0 + 1 = 1 (the carry from the previous bit is discarded)
The answer is 10 in binary, which is 2.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What carry do you want to ignore? Are you looking for the bitwise exclusive OR?

Comment: Perhaps you want to trim a string to 32 characters?

Comment: Please provide an example so that we understand exactly which carry is to be ignored. Right now the question is ambiguous.

Comment: Simply the carry that results from simple binary addition. This is a puzzle I have been given at school.

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking for the bitwise XOR (exclusive OR) which will provide the following outputs for the given inputs:

```
^ | 0 | 1
--+---+--
0 | 0 | 1
--+---+--
1 | 1 | 0
```

It behaves like binary addition ( `1+1 = 10`) but ignores the overflow if both operands are `1`.

```
int a = 5; // 101
int b = 6; // 110 

a ^ b; // 3 or 011
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just an `XOR` of the two integers in binary. In Java you can do

```
result = v1 ^ v2;
```